# Enlarge + Convert image or single page pdf into a multiple page pdf

Tags: pdf, image-conversion

Enlarge + Convert image or single page pdf into a multiple page pdf

Imagine you want a gigantic poster on the wall your apartment.

The picture for that poster could be an anime character or a page from a page of a problem set in school. Let's say the latter.

You want to convert that single page/single image into a pdf of many pages long each having a rectangular puzzle piece of that image blown up large. With no bezel/white edges, just printed on the entire sheet of paper.

You can then print this many page long PDF and then re-assemble the 8.5 by 11 sheets of paper with tape on your apartment wall. It's like putting together a jigsaw puzzle except the pieces are already in order and are just rectangles. Voila, you have a very tacky way to create a giant poster.

Assume that you have a color printer with for practical purposes ink.

The above is what I'm looking for.
Specifications:
- Windows 10 laptop
- Willing to pay maybe 20$ if there is software that can do this in a very easy, fast way
- This can already be done by tediously cutting and pasting pieces of a picture but I'm looking for something that can do all those repetitive action for you

Comment: Please note that most (all?) physical printers cannot print to the very edge of a piece of paper. I'm not sure why, but it is a hardware restriction. So you are still left with a lot of cutting to remove white edges.

Comment: On a slightly related topic: [PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) is the equivalent program for jpgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Adobe Reader](https://get.adobe.com/reader/)

Adobe Reader is a rather popular and fairly powerful pdf viewer. It has the option to scale pages to larger sized and tile them on separate sheets of paper. Simply choose the poster option and select the scale and orientation (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot]

The "no white edge" requirement in your question cannot be met by software alone. As pointed by Ryan in the comments, printers have physical margins which they are unable to print outside, these margins are usually smaller than the page size for home printers. As a workaround, Adobe Reader has the option to print cut marks on the sheets so you can trim them before taping. You just need to check the corresponding box.

[Here is the link to a more detailed help page on the Adobe website.](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html)

Adobe Reader and the new Adobe Acrobat Reader DC are free of charge, but do note before downloading that there are a couple of optional checkboxes that will install additional and usually unwanted software if you don't uncheck them first.